# Laravel - Why is my @section with parameters being placed wrongfully on top?

Tags: php, html, laravel

I have 2 blade.php files: `home.blade.php` and `customer.blade.php`.
What I want is to make each HTML table page containing 20 rows of customer data and the table data is fetched from `Customer` model. The structure should look like this:

```
<body>
   <div
        class="body_right-wrapper_content-viewer"
   >
       <div
           class="content_table-wrapper"
       >
       </div>
   </div>
</body>
```

It seems like when I use `@yield('content')` without parameters like `$pageNumber` and pass it to

```
@section('content')
<div></div>
@endsection
```

,the table content
fits perfectly inside the `div`. But when passing `@section('content',$pageNumber)` with parameter `$pageNumber`, the `@endsection` must be removed which makes `@section('content',$pageNumber)` being placed on top of the screen.

When I inspect the errors in browser, it turns out that the HTML codes are parsed like this:

```
<body>
   <div
        class="content_table-wrapper"
   >
   </div>
   <div
        class="body_right-wrapper_content-viewer"
   >
   </div>
</body>
```

Here are the codes:

`home.blade.php`

```
<?php
    $pageNumber = 1;
?>

<div
    class="body_right-wrapper_content-viewer"
    style="
        flex: 1;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: #FFFFFF;
        border-radius: 21px;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
    "
>
    @yield('content',$pageNumber)
</div>
```

`customers.blade.php`:

```
<?php
    $pageNumber = 1;
?>

@extends('home')
@section('content',$pageNumber)
    <div
        class="content_table-wrapper"
        style="
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            min-width: 1000px;
            min-height: 600px;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
        "
    >
        <table></table>
    </div>
```

Comment: From what I understand `@section('content', $pageNumber)` defines a section which has content `$pageNumber` and nothing else  and `@yield('content', $pageNumber)` will yield `$pageNumber` if the content section is not defined. That does not sound like what you are trying to do. If you are trying to include with parameters the parameters go in the `@include` directive (which I don't see being used here)

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to use @section:

Short:

```
@section('sectionName', 'ValueToSetIt')
```

Long format:

```
@section('sectionName')
ValueToSetIt<IncludingHtml/>
@endsection
```

You cannot combine the 2 ways to forward additional parameters to the layout. For this you should make multiple sections. or find another way, for example including an component directly in your page or use a base layout view model or something.

### Solution

In your case, use 2 sections:

```
@yield('content')
@yield('pageNumber')
```